# proof of which x for which sin(x) can be written in terms of real radicals

Tags: trigonometry, prime-numbers

Is there a constructive proof of the following statement?

> Expressions in real radicals exist for a trigonometric function of a
>   rational multiple of $\pi$ if and only if the denominator of the fully
>   reduced rational multiple is a power of $2$ by itself or the product of
>   a power of $2$ with the product of distinct Fermat primes.

I'm writing a computer algebra system, and it would be nice if the algorithm for rewriting trigonometric expressions in terms of real radicals wouldn't have to consider every denominator case separately. Ideally, it would work for any value for which the above statement says such conversion is possible, even for Fermat primes that haven't been discovered yet, memory limitations aside. I figure if a constructive proof of the statement exists, it could be used as a model for the algorithm.

Comment: Someone published a book with the construction of the 65537-gon. It is a thick book